# Describe the relative topology of the unit circle as a subspace of the plane

Tags: general-topology

A question from Dugundji's book which I don't even understand the statement.

Describe the relative topology of $\{z: |z|=1\}$ as a subspace of ${\mathbb{R}}^{2}$.

What do they mean by "describe"? I don't understand what they are asking for. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I don't know what describe means either.  The open sets are countable unions of disjoint open arcs; that's one way to describe the topology.  It's a compact connected 1-dimensional manifold (the only one up to homeomorphism).

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the exercise is not very precisely stated, and I don't myself know exactly what Dugundji was intending here (and not, I think, due to any lack of understanding of basic topology).

The best I can do is to suggest a reasonable problem which *could* be what Dugundji had in mind: show that "open intervals" (**edit**: Jonas Meyer's terminology *open arcs* is better) on the unit circle form a base for the subspace topology.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you, it is clear now.

Comment: @Paulo: you're welcome.  If you're fully satisfied with this answer, please click the "accept answer box" to accept it.  (This gives me a little "reputation", but more importantly it keeps things tidy on the site.  It is very convenient to be able to tell whether a question has been answered or not, and unanswered questions periodically get kicked to the top of the queue.)